# what is the app that i need to select for java script

Tags: zapier

In Zapier what is the App that I need to select in the first step of Zapier so that I can use javascript.

the highlighted one is what I need:

[image]

Comment: As homepage says, Zapier integrates apps together. So you need to choose an app you need to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

You select `Code by Zapier`, then Javascript:

[image]